# Pipe to perl for sort and pipe to other command

Tags: perl

The following snippet sorts version numbers.  I tested it in a script and it seems to be correct.

```
sort {
       my @left  = split( /\./, $a );
       my @right = split( /\./, $b );

       if ( $left[0] <=> $right[0] ) {
          return $left[0] <=> $right[0];
       }

       if ( $left[1] <=> $right[1] ) {
            return $left[1] <=> $right[1] 
        }
        elsif ( @left < @right ) {
            return -1;
        }

        return @left < @right ? -1 : 1;
} @versions
```

How can I make this more succinct/less verbose and run it in a pipe sequence.
I.e. `numbers_generator | perl -e SORT_HERE | other_command`

Comment: Are you sure `1.9` goes before `1.1.1`?

Comment: @choroba:hm you are right. I am messing something up since it outputs 1.9 before 1.1.1 but it should be the reverse

Comment: @choroba:good catch! Thank you. I updated post

Comment: If you have GNU `sort`, you can use its version sort with `-V`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this easier and more reliably with the standard [version module](https://metacpan.org/pod/version).

```
sort { version->parse($a) <=> version->parse($b) } @versions
```

As for a pipe, that depends on what is receiving this. You can accept them as command line arguments (ie. `@ARGV`) or as lines to stdin. You can output space separated, or on separate lines.

Here it is taking the versions as lines on stdin and outputting as separate lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use version;

say join "\n",
    sort {
      version->parse($a) <=> version->parse($b)
    }
    map { chomp; $_ }
    <STDIN>;
```

And it would be used like so.

```
$ echo -e '19.0\n2.9\n0.1.23.45' | sort_versions 
0.1.23.45
2.9
19.0
```

Then the other end reads versions from STDIN line by line.

---

But if you have GNU sort, you should use `sort -V` as [Benjamin W. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123655/pipe-to-perl-for-sort-and-pipe-to-other-command/50124381#comment87266236_50123655).

Comment: 1) Do I need to have a script and not have it part of a pipe sequence?

Comment: 2) Is the `versions` module part of perl or extra install lib?

Comment: Version module is part of the core modules since Perl v5.9.0 @Jim (command to find core modules is `corelist version`)

Comment: @Jim 1) Pipes don't care if you're using a oneliner or a script. It's better to put this in a script if you're going to use it more than once for readability, testing, and maintenance. 2) version has come standard with Perl for the last 10 years.

Comment: I was wondering why should I prefer `version` that the simple comparison suggested by @choroba? Is there any corner cases I would miss or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Jim For all the reasons you use an existing, well tested module rather than writing your own code. Corner cases, like `1.2.3.4` or `v1.2.3.4`, are one, plus all the other cases we haven't thought of but the people working on version over the years have. And all those bugs you don't have to worry about. As important is maintainability. `version->parse` is easy to understand at a glance, it's well documented, and `version` can solve other problems. In contrast, hand written code must be studied to be understood: what does it do; what are its limits; does it have bugs; how do I reuse it?

Answer (score 2):

Comparing lengths of the arrays makes no sense.

Comparing the first pair, or the second one if the first one is equal, and the same for the third one, should be enough:

```
   return $left[0] <=> $right[0]
       || $left[1] <=> $right[1]
       || $left[2] <=> $right[2]
```

You need to disable warnings so you don't get "Use of uninitialized value" when comparing two versions of different lengths.

So, the pipeline would look like

```
numbers_generator \
| perl -e 'print sort { @l = split /\./, $a; @r = split /\./, $b; $l[0] <=> $r[0] || $l[1] <=> $r[1] || $l[2] <=> $r[2] } <>' \
| other_command
```

Comment: So comparing with `undef` will give correct results? And how would I "plug" this within a pipe sequence?

Comment: `undef` will evaluate as 0 in a numeric comparison, so it could give incorrect results if the other input might be a negative number

Comment: Why would I need to disable warnings. Wouldn't the following work to avoid warnings? `|| ($left[2] || 0 ) <=> ($right[2] || 0 )`

Comment: @Jim: You don't need to. Using || works well, but is less readable and more to type.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers_generator |
perl -Mversion -le'
   chomp( @a = <> );
   print for sort { version->parse($a) cmp version->parse($b) } @a;
' |
other_command
```

Comment: The `version` is that extra lib or part of perl defaults?

Comment: See comment above. It is a core module

Comment: I was wondering why should I prefer `version` that the simple comparison suggested by @choroba? Is there any corner cases I would miss or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use Perl here. You could use `sort`, specifying `.` as a field delimeter, and then sorting each field `n`umerically

```
numbers_generator | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n | other_command
```

Note this is for *up to* 3-digit version numbers.

Edit: *up to*

Comment: That is why I use perl. Because I need to handle 2 **and** 3-digit version numbers.

Comment: If there is another way I am open as long as it handles 2 and 3 digits

Comment: Or use `sort -V` if you have GNU sort.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: That is the problem. I don't have that available and I am looking for a replacement that would work for Mac

Comment: @Jim You can use GNU coreutils via homebrew: `brew install coreutils`

Comment: But... This does work with 2 **and** 3-digit version numbers.