# Why is the version sort order reversed?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have the following code to sort version numbers:

```
chomp(my @versions = <>);  
my @sorted_versions = sort {  
                        version->parse( $a ) cmp version->parse( $b )
                    } @versions;  
print "$_\n" for @sorted_versions;
```

If I pipe the following file:

```
cat version_file   
15.8  
15.8.1
```

The output is:

```
15.8.1  
15.8
```

Why? It should have been:

```
15.8  
15.8.1
```

I have checked that the `cmp` returns 1 when running the script

Comment: `cmp` returns 1 when left argument is greater than right one. Is the problem somewhere inside `version->parse`?

Comment: I think the problem is that `15.8` is interpreted as `15.800000` whereas `15.8.1` is interpreted as `15.008001`. You should convert `15.8` to the more modern format: `15.8.0`

Comment: @HåkonHægland:Isn't there a way to achieve what I want without changing the version format?

Comment: @Jim Maybe. But why not just loop through `@versions` before the `sort` and fix it up?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: You mean convert `15.8` to `15.8.0` and sort? I could and it would work but I find that doing that is complicating things a bit. Check here and comments for what I am trying to do and using `version` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123655/pipe-to-perl-for-sort-and-pipe-to-other-command/50126113#50126113

Comment: @Jim I am not sure how it would complicate, but anyway you do not need to preprocess the list if that is the problem. You could also define a sub like `sub fixup { $_[0] =~ s/^[^.]*\.[^.]*\K$/.0/r }` and then do `version->parse( fixup($a) ) cmp version->parse( fixup($b) )` in the `sort` sub.

`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I know that `$1 $2 etc` capture groups but what is `.0` and how does that regex work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170482/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-jim).

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for `version`](https://metacpan.org/pod/version#How-to-parse()-a-version) has this

> Dotted-decimal: bare v-strings (v1.2.3) and strings with more than one decimal point and a leading 'v' ("v1.2.3"); NOTE you can technically use a v-string or strings with a leading-v and only one decimal point (v1.2 or "v1.2"), but you will confuse both yourself and others

The problem is that `15.8` parses as `v5.800.0` whereas `15.8.1` becomes `v15.8.1`

You can read more of relevance at [`version::Internals`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version/Internals.pod)

Comment: Hm but that is not what I have as versions. Is the only option to preprocess `15.8` to make it `15.8.0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `v` in front of your version.

```
chomp(my @versions = <>);
my @sorted_versions = sort {
    version->parse( "v$a" ) cmp version->parse( "v$b" )
} @versions;
print "$_\n" for @sorted_versions;
```